# Weird visual bug when running tKinter code

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to code a little game for a school project and this is a part of the name input code. When i run this part of the code it leaves me with a visual bug. This is the code that i have:

```
from tkinter import *

def retrieve_input():
    input = Naam1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(input)
    input = Naam2.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(input)
    input = Naam3.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(input)

def create_kiezen():
    global Naam1
    global Naam2
    global Naam3

    kiezen = Tk()
    kiezen.geometry('600x600')
    kiezen.title('Namen invoeren!')
    kiezen.configure(background='darkgrey')
    Spelen = Button(kiezen, text='Begin!', bd='5', height='2', width='15',
                    command=lambda: [kiezen.destroy(), Spelmenu()])
    Terug = Button(kiezen, text='Terug', bd='5', height='2', width='15', command=lambda: [kiezen.destroy(), menu()])
    Spelen.pack(anchor='s', side='right')
    Terug.pack(anchor='s', side='left')
    kiezen.minsize(600, 600)
    kiezen.maxsize(600, 600)

    naamblok = Canvas(kiezen, width=400, height=200)
    naamblok.place(x=100, y=100)
    Opslaan=Button(naamblok, height=1, width=10, text='Opslaan', command=lambda: retrieve_input())
    Opslaan.place(x=160, y=150)

    Naam1=Text(naamblok, width=10, height=5)
    Naam1.place(x=160, y=40)
    Naam2= Text(naamblok, width=10, height=5)
    Naam2.place(x=160, y=60)
    Naam3=Text(naamblok, width=10, height=1)
    Naam3.place(x=160, y=80)

    mainloop()

create_kiezen()
```

There are three input fields but for some reason, there is one input field that is really big. It overlaps my button and I don't really know how to fix this.

Any helps is appreciated!

Comment: Not one, but two.  The second one overlap the first one.  Change `height=5` to `height=1` or change `Text` widgets to `Entry` widgets.

Comment: I changed both the heights and now they look like how I want them to look. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: If you use `grid` or `pack` instead of `place`, you won't have to compute the coordinates of the widgets. This code will only work for a specific resolution and font, but might not work on other systems or with different fonts.